# How do I combine my utm_cookie setting scripts into one script?

Tags: javascript, tags, google-tag-manager

My request is probably pretty simple - but I am not sure if it aligns with best practices, so I suppose my question is two-fold.

1. How do I combine my 9 separate scripts into 1 single script?
2. Is this a good idea - or should I keep them all separate?

Right now, my scripts take individual utm parameters from a query string and store them in a cookie. I do this for the following utm parameters & click ids. I am doing this inside of Google Tag Manager.

1. utm_source
2. utm_medium
3. utm_campaign
4. utm_content
5. utm_term
6. gclid
7. fbclid
8. msclkid

My script looks like this for each utm parameter or click id:

```js
<script>

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    baseDomain = '.website.com';
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; domain=" + baseDomain + "; path=/";
}

  createCookie("utm_source","{{url - utm source}}",1)

  
 </script>
```

Overall, I worry that by combining them, I'll then have a bunch of values as "undefined" if one of the parameters exist, but the others do not.

Answer (score 0):

Creating nine separate first party cookies is not a good idea, since the amount of cookies a browser can store is limited. Also each of these values is sent to the server via cookie headers, which makes you request larger than necessary and might create just enough metadata on your server to become a security/privacy problem.

The best option IMO is to store all your values in a single cookie as a string of key/value pairs, and the best option for that is an url format:

```
?utm_source=source&utm_medium=medium
```

etc (this must be query string format, so the question mark at the start is mandatory).

The reason I think this is the best way is because GTM has a built-in url parser, that allows you to easily get the individual values (and set default for none existings values) by setting the source for the url variable to the value of your first party cookie.

After you have saved the complete string (w/o missing values) in your first party cookie, you can read it back on the following pages via a first party cookie variable:

[image: cookie variable config]

Then you can use the output from that variable to read individual parts via a url type variable, where you set the type to "query", the key to the utm key you want to extract, and the source to the variable with your first party cookie value:

[image: url variable configuration]

You can set default values as required for missing values (i.e. if a key does not exist in your cookie string).

As a hint, when you set your cookie use a [custom template](https://tagmanager.google.com/gallery/#/owners/gtm-templates-anto-hed/templates/cookie-creator) instead of a custom HTML tag (custom HTML requires eval, which is slow and generally not good practice).

Now you have one cookie instead of nine, and a simple solution to get to the values or return a sensible default.

Comment: I did as you suggested. Thank you for the recommendation! The only trouble I am running into now is that my `URL - Query - utm_medium` isn't grabbing the data from the stored cookie when I go to `More Settings --> URL Source`. Any reason why it wouldn't be pulling the data from that?

Comment: Nothing that comes to mind (unless you might have forgotten the leading question mark - without it, GTM will not recognize your cookie string as query parameter format and will be unable to resolve the values). Can you add a screenshot to your question, so we can check the configuration?

Comment: My little workaround did not work because it kept setting the QueryString cookie as `?`. 

Do you know a good way to capture the entire query string parameter with the `?` included?